# Trying to get connects of URL with PHP CURL , but no success

Tags: php, url, curl

here is my URL: https://webservices-dev.compuscan.co.za:9443/PersonStatusService/user2/password2/8310240031083/XML

i am try to get its content with PHP curl but no success hope some can help.

here is my code:

```
// you can add anoother curl options too
// see here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php 
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);             // Use POST method
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=1&var2=2&var3=3");  // Define POST values
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$output = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($output);

curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

$url = "https://webservices-dev.compuscan.co.za:9443/PersonStatusService/user2/password2/8310240031083/XML" ;


$variablee = get_data($url);
echo $variable;
```

Comment: Try to use [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and [`curl_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am getting results as expected.

It should be

```
$variablee = get_data($url);
echo $variablee; //<--- Must be $variablee (as you have defined it above)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Array ( [url] =>
>   https://webservices-dev.compuscan.co.za:9443/PersonStatusService/user2/password2/8310240031083/XML
>   [content_type] => text/plain; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 200
>   [header_size] => 81 [request_size] => 192 [filetime] => -1
>   [ssl_verify_result] => 19 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.544
>   [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.343 [pretransfer_time] =>
>   1.186 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 656 [speed_download] => 424 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 656
>   [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 1.544
>   [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] =>
>   196.34.30.23 [primary_port] => 9443 [local_ip] => 192.168.72.37 [local_port] => 61090 [redirect_url] => )
>   8310240031083CLAIRECSAPLARN1983/10/24FY2012/03/242013/09/308 SKALIE
>   STWEST ACRES EXT 1312012013/08/130768333118

Comment: Thanks Shankar; i see that in my code the $variablee; was spelt correctly. in turn i tried the code on another server and it works so i am guessing it has something to do with the PHP config?

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; 
Windows NT 6.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($httpCode == 404) {
curl_close($ch);
return '404';
} else {
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
}
```

This function worked perfectly for me, maybe somebody finds it useful as I did. I'm not pretending to answer your question (well, I'm 9 months late) but solve people's similar questions about a similar issue.